# random NextInt JAVA

Tags: java, random

Hola queria ayuda con una parte de un codigo, en la clase mazo la funcion mezclar() genera un numero random para mezclar las cartas, pero no entiendo lo que hace **int p = r.nextInt(this.cartas.length-this.posPrimCarta)+this.posPrimCarta;** .
En la primera iteracion se toman valores de 0 a 40.
En la segunda iteracion se toman valores de 1 a 39.
Pero que pasa cuando se tomen los valores (19,20) cosa que los numeros aleatorios que se puedan tomar son de 19 a 19. No tiene sentido.
Queria saber como funciona el nextInt exactamente ?

```
public class Carta {
    /* irep
     * (numero>=1 and numero<=7) or (numero>=10 and numero<=12)
     * and
     * (palo>=1 && palo<=4)
     * */
    
    int palo; // 1 = espada, 2 = copa, 3 = basto, 4= oro
    int numero;
    
    Carta(int p, int n){
        this.numero=n;
        this.palo=p;
    }
    
    void mostrar() {
        String[] palos = {"espada", "copa", "basto", "oro"};
        System.out.println(this.numero + " " + palos[this.palo-1]);
    }
    
    boolean CartaEsValida() {
        boolean numVal = (this.numero>=1 && this.numero<=7) || (this.numero>=10 && this.numero<=12);
        boolean paloVal = this.palo>=1 && this.palo<=4;
        return numVal && paloVal;
    }
    
}
```

Aca esta la clase Mazo:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Mazo {
    //variable de instancia
    Carta[] cartas;
    int posPrimCarta;

    Mazo() {
        this.cartas = new Carta[40];
        int t = 0;
        for (int p = 1; p <= 4; p++) {
            for (int n = 1; n <= 7; n++) {
                this.cartas[t]=new Carta(p,n);
                t++;
            }
            for (int n = 10; n <= 12; n++) {
                this.cartas[t]=new Carta(p,n);
                t++;
            }
        }
        this.posPrimCarta = 0;
    }

    
    void mostrar() {
        for (int i = this.posPrimCarta; i < this.cartas.length; i++) {
            this.cartas[i].mostrar();
        }
    }
    
    void mezclar() {
        //mezclar mazo
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = this.posPrimCarta; i < this.cartas.length; i++) {
            int p = r.nextInt(this.cartas.length-this.posPrimCarta)+this.posPrimCarta;
            Carta c = this.cartas[i];
            this.cartas[i] = this.cartas[p];
            this.cartas[p] = c;
        }               
    }
    
    Carta repartir() {
        Carta c = this.cartas[this.posPrimCarta];
        this.cartas[this.posPrimCarta] = null;
        this.posPrimCarta++;
        return c;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El método [nextInt(numero)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) devolverá un número aleatorio entre 0 (inclusivo) y el número pasado en el argumento (exclusivo), es decir, en este caso, si aun no se ha repartido ninguna carta, este número aleatorio será entre 0 y 39 en todas las iteraciones, no 0 y 40, 1 y 39, etc. como piensas.

Si se ha repartido alguna carta, este número irá decreciendo, de 0 a 38, de 0 a 37, etc., para solo barajar las cartas restantes.